# loading all css files from 'assets' directory in NUXT

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'd like to load a couple of css files from the assets folder in my nuxt project.

currently I'm loading files individually via `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  head: {
     css: [
        '~/assets/css/fonts.css'
     ],
  }
}
```

which works perfectly fine for a single file. is there any way to import all files at once that are in the `/assets/css` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an alternative way that you can import your css or scss files by sass.

1. Create a folder in your assets called `scss` : `/assets/scss/`.
2. Install [import-glob-loader](https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader) by running this command:

```
npm install import-glob-loader --save-dev
```

3. Create a file in `assets/scss/` path call it `main.scss`.
   Open `main.scss` and add this code on it:

```
@import "imports/**/*";
```

3. Create a folder in `assets/scss/` call it `imports/` that involves all your css codes.
4. create your css files in this `assets/scss/imports` path.

[image]

5. Go to `nuxt.config.js` and add this code in that file:

```
 css: ['@/assets/scss/main.scss'],
```